# Is there a way to include a native Windows library in a MAUI project?

Tags: android, windows, include, native, maui

I have a native Windows library I'd like to include as part of Windows build/package in my MAUI app.  Is there a way to do this where it won't be included in the builds/packages of the other platforms?

I found a way to do this with Android native libraries: I simply place them in (ProjectDir)\Resources\lib\(Architecture), where (Architecture) is, for example, 'arm64-v8a'.  Then I can simply flag them in the .csproj file as an AndroidNativeLibrary and all's well; they show up in my Android build and don't appear in any of the other builds (Windows, IOS, etc.).

Things I've tried:

1. Manually copying the Windows native lib (a DLL) to the generated AppX folder via a postbuild script.  Not ideal.  For one, the AppX folder isn't technically generated until after the build is finished; it's part of a packaging step (I believe).  So, this kind of works, but isn't really the proper solution.  I want the DLL to automatically be included by the packager.
2. Adding the DLL as an item to the .csproj.  This means it gets automatically included in the AppX package, but is still not ideal as it subsequently winds up in every platform's build.
3. The most promising:  referenced the DLL via a 'file' element in (ProjectDir)\Platforms\Windows\app.manifest.  However, it doesn't seem like this manifest file plays any role in the build/packaging.  Rather Package.appxmanifest seems to be the file that matters.  If I throw intentional typos into app.manifest, building and packaging still succeed.  I also added app.manifest to the csproj explicitly via ; it doesn't seem to care.

Anyway, any ideas/insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a fantastic article that solves my problem:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/cpp/

Not sure how I didn’t find this before; I was looking forever.